# Substract value of one attribute from the previous day value in ELasticsearch for Kibana Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

My elastic index has 3 attributes - accountNumber, timestamp and score. I want to caclulate the difference in score from today to previous day for each account and build visualization for the difference. How can I calculate the difference in score for each acount. Need help in scripted / runtime variable. New to elasticsearch

Tried few ways from dashboard and scripted variable.. but no luck